# Question about Reporting and Data Warehousing Software bundled with SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services, data-warehouse

We currently use SQL Server 2005 Enterprise for our fairly large application, that has its roots in pre SQL Server 7.0.  The tables are normalized and designed mainly for the application.  The developers for the most part have the legacy SQL Server mindset.  Only using the part of TSQL that existed back in 7.0, not using any of the new features of tsql or that are bundled with 2005.

We're currently trying to build on demand reports using some crappy third party software, and will eventually try to build a data warehouse using more of the same crappy third party software (name removed to protect the guilty, don't ask I will not tell).  The rationale for this was that we didn't want to spend more money to buy this additional software from Microsoft (this was not my decision, I had no input, but is my problem now).  But from what I can tell is that Enterprise includes all of these tools, or am I missing something?

**What comes bundled with SQL Server 2005 Enterprise as far as reporting and data warehousing?  Will we need to purchase anything else? is there actually anything else that can be purchased from Microsoft in this regard?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first - I would go with 2008 R2 for that regard, much better for reporting.

- DAta warehousing in 2005 is just that. 2008 did introduce optimizatoins for star schemata in the query optimizer.
- 2005 I think has report services that you can use - though they got a LOT better with 2008 and 2008 R2 (graphs etc.)
- Besides that think getting rid of SQL for analysis - the data warehouse should get loaded into cubes in SQL Server Analysis Services and run the reports against those.

All that (reporting services, analysis services) is part of the enterprise edition you use. There is hardly any use for something else unless you have unusual needs.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise edition contains Reporting Services that you can install that. It is a powerful service for reporting.

Answer (score 0):

If you find you're unhappy with Reporting Services (seems to not work well for about 35% of the people who try it), please take a look at [Windward Reports](http://www.windwardreports.com/). With that said, I hope it does work well for you as that is your least expensive and quickest route forward.